# WordPress custom JS routes for childs url in a Custom Post Type child post

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have added an JS router ([Navigo.js](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo)) and like to use it on a Costum Post Type post. But I can't get it to work.

The url struktur I like to go work is this:
/ [CTP] / [post_title] / [JS router]

```
function paper_post_type() {
    register_post_type('paper',
        [
            'labels' => array (
                'name' => 'Paper',
                'menu_name' => 'Paper',
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'has_archive' => false
        ]
    );
}
add_action('init', 'paper_post_type');

add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 
        '^paper/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?paper=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^paper/([^/]*)/', 'index.php?paper=$matches[1]', 'top');
});
```